# Is there any jquery plugin that does google images like smooth hover effect?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, hover, thumbnails

Is there any jquery plugin that does google images like smooth hover effect? Any plugin to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `.animate()`, it's a built in function, just define the easing time and it will flow smoothly. See the demo on their wiki: http://api.jquery.com/animate/